# Encoding.GetEncodings() is not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core, .net-6.0

Following code block working well on C# Interactive Compiler

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Interactive Compiler version 4.2.0-4.22252.24 ()
Loading context from 'CSharpInteractive.rsp'.
Type "#help" for more information.
> using System.Text;
> var codepages = Encoding.GetEncodings().Select(x => x.GetEncoding()).ToList();
> foreach (var cp in codepages) { Console.WriteLine($"{cp.HeaderName} {cp.EncodingName} ({cp.CodePage})"); }
```

output

```
1. IBM037 IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada) (37)
2. IBM437 OEM United States (437)
3. IBM500 IBM EBCDIC (International) (500)
..
..
..
138. x-iscii-pa ISCII Punjabi (57011)
139. utf-7 Unicode (UTF-7) (65000)
140. utf-8 Unicode (UTF-8) (65001)
```

But whenever I want to run it in .net 6.0 winform application

```
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initView();
            cbEncodings.Items.Clear();
            var codepages = Encoding.GetEncodings().Select(x => x.GetEncoding()).ToList();
            foreach (var e in codepages)
            {
                cbEncodings.Items.Add($"{e.EncodingName} ({e.CodePage})");
            }
        }
```

it's only lists 7 elements

[image: Output]

[image]

what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);` before your code (i.e. before `var codepages = Encoding.GetEncodings().Select(x => x.GetEncoding()).ToList();`), then you get the full list. Details are in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencodings?view=net-6.0.

Comment: `RegisterProvider()` can be added to `Program.cs` before `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();` or in the Constructor of the starting Form (to make sure it's applied application-wide, before any piece code enumerates the Encodings).